# Is this considered a POST or GET request?

Tags: javascript, post, servlets, get, request

I saw the below code in w3school. I was wondering is this considered a POST request or a GET request. I only changed the action location to go to a java servlet rather than php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" action="/action">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br> Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
  </form>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<form>` defaults to GET.  How the server handles the URL makes no difference

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`<form>`'s default method is `GET`**.

So it is considered as a GET request. You'll see all the parameters are being binded to the URL once the form is submitted.

---

**EDIT** (answering [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251403/is-this-considered-a-post-or-get-request/51251419#comment89481975_51251419)):

Easiest way to change the method of the form is to mention it in `method` attribute in the `<form>` tag.

```
<form method='POST' id="myForm">
```

Or you can use javascript as below,

```
document.getElementById("myForm").method = "POST";
```

Comment: As a side note, how do you choose the submit to be a POST or GET in the javascript (if that's even possible)? In other words, is it possible to keep the form as it is but change the javascript so that the submission is POST.

Comment: @QwertyQwerts I have edited the post. Check it now.

Comment: Thankyou so much for you help :)

Comment: @QwertyQwerts My pleasure... Cheers! :)